# xproc and XQuery 3.1

Tags: xquery, xproc

from [XProc: W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#c.xquery) / p:xquery

> The p:xquery step applies an [XQuery 1.0] query

can I use xproc with XQuery 3.1?

Comment: See the [eXist xprocxq extension](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/extensions.xml#module_xprocxq).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it. New XQuery implementation on top of **MarkLogic**, but **eXist** accept just old implementation. [XProc](https://readtiger.com/wkp/en/XProc)

Answer (score 1):

I think the XProc spec mentions [XQuery 1.0] simply because there was no XQuery 3.x at the time when the XProc 1.0 came out. (The same applies to the `p:xslt` step and support for XSLT 3.0.) It is difficult to claim support for future versions of specifications without knowing what they will look like and what impact they may have.

Having said that, however, I think XProc implementers take a pragmatic approach and usually support the latest versions of the specifications. For instance, [Calumet](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-4242) with the xDB plug-in supports whatever XQuery version that xDB supports (3.1 as of xDB version 11).